# Input tab in windows command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, ascii

The C++ code has

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and I want one of my arguments to be tab (ASCII character 9). How do I do this? (This is on a Windows 10).

Comment: Do you mean, how do you enter such command parameter in a terminal window? You cannot (too hard). But you can put the command in a batch file and enclose the tab char in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell: Type for this argument: quote, ALT + NUM 009 , quote. That's, type " then press and hold ALT then type 009 on the numeric pad then release ALT then type ".

This will be echoed like:

your-command arg1 **"^I"** arg2